# Not Able to create new package under src/main/java in 'Java Resources' in Dynamic Web Projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc

Since yesterday, I have this problem in all my Dynamic Web Projects. New package is not getting created under the source folder in 'Java Resources'. It seems to get created in 'Java resources' but not under src/main/java, but parallel to it. I have cleaned the project, restarted eclipse, rebuilt the project, checked the build pat and nothing seems to work. Please help me, i have attached a screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtAdT.png

This has been resolved! Someone pointed out to me it was just a matter of refreshing after creating the package, then in the project explporer view, the new package is shown correctly

this is how i am creating a new package in eclipse:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmoCh.png

Comment: "Java Resources" isn't a folder, it's an organizational node that only exists in the Project Explorer view. How are you filling out the wizard when creating a new package, specifically the Source folder text field? Show us.

Comment: @nitind i am doing it the normal way. let me show you, i will edit the question to inlcude this. i am new to using stack overflow. so please tell me if i am doing anything wrong. Thank you

Comment: Right-click the created package and choose _Properties: Resource_: what is the _Path_? In case the path is `/SpringMVCFormBasedRevision/src/main/java/com/glearning/main` as it should be, make sure your Eclipse is up to date to avoid facing a glitch that has already been fixed. Otherwise, tell what path is shown.

Comment: @howlger the file path is correct : /SpringMVCFormBasedRevision/src/main/java/com/glearning/main                           
 this glitch happened for the first time since i stated to use eclipse. how do i make sure eclipse is upto date? i am currently using 2022-12 version.

Comment: You are two releases behind. If I remember correctly, this is something that has been fixed. Does _Help > Check for Updates_ help? But it's only a glitch, showing a new created package one level higher than it is. Maybe closing and re-opening a project can be used as workaround.

Comment: @howlger i will update my eclipse as you told me. this issue was resolved when I refreshed the project after the package as created and appearing at a higher hierarchy. after hitiing a refresh, the package comes to the correct location as expected. but when it was not in correct alignment, the path was still correct. so  guess it is some project explorer view issue